# How to avoid business logic (if-else/ looping) inside a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view where it has all kind of business logic... which comprises with foreach, if else statements.

As per the coding standards nothing should be written inside view. Here is my code. Can any one please suggest me how to move the business logic outside the view

@if (qList.Data.GUIType.ToUpper().Equals(ConstantsBE.TEXTBOX))

I will loop through the model in view and inside the foreach loop again i will have too many if else statements. Now i wanted the functionality but the code should be moved from view.

Comment: Can you provide a reference where it says that "coding standards nothing should be written inside view"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant really, and you don't need to. This isnt static HTML content there will always be some functional code int he view, if you find you using the same loginin multiple views you can create HTML helpers or templates.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason i have decided to do so, is because the view page is looking ugly. So, wanted to move. Thanks guys your suggestion really helping me :)